# Определение части речи (слово "когда")

Tags: морфология

Все начиналось примерно так, как грезилось волчице, когда волчата были ещё малы. Слово «когда» какой частью речи является?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

```
Слово «когда» какой частью речи является?
```

Союз, присоединяющий придаточное предложение времени.